# How to build scheme that I can use to build for TestFlight deployment that will have the app use a development URL

Tags: ios, xcode

How to build scheme that I can use to build for TestFlight deployment that will have the app use a development URL to pull data from, and then have another build scheme for production that will use the production URL when the app runs. Any suggestions how this could be implemented?

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate your existing scheme and choose another *Build Configuration* (not *Release*) under *Archive*. Probably you can use *Debug* there, if your debug configuration contains the necessary settings for compiling with the different URL (e. g. macro definitions). If not, you must create a new build configuration with this settings.

BTW.: I had the same need in my current app. Instead of creating different apps I've implemented a hidden settings dialog which allows changing the URL, and you can test your app with release code even its loaded from the app store.